# Why does incentivize exist as a verb but disincentivize does not?

Tags: verbs, nouns, dictionaries

I ask this because incentive and disincentive both exist, but annoyingly, autocorrect and spellcheckers all over refuse to accept disincentivize while gladly accepting incentivize.

Comment: It is a problem of your spell checker, not of the English language - To ***Disincentivize***  : http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/disincentivize - probably because the term is relatively recent : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disincentivize&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisincentivize%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Damn, seems most spellcheckers don't accept this. When I google incentivize a definition comes up as a verb but when I google disincentivize it changes the result to disincentivize and as a noun.

Comment: Yes, it's a perfectly useful verb. Spellcheckers, grammar checkers, and automated online services need to be trained (when possible).